# Reflect on nested namespace

Tags: ruby, namespaces, nested

I am trying to find the root class/module of a nested namespace.

Is this the most efficient way to find it? I don't like that I am converting to a string. It seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

```
class Foo
   class Bar
     def parent
        Object.const_get self.class.to_s.split(/::/).first
     end
   end
end

Foo::Bar.new.parent #=> Foo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `Module.nesting`

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz
      p Module.nesting       # => [Foo::Bar::Baz, Foo::Bar, Foo]
      p Module.nesting.last  # => Foo
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @sawa why doesn't the following work? `Foo::Bar::Baz.class_eval{ Module.nesting } # => []` nor `Foo::Bar::Baz.module_eval{ Module.nesting } # => []` nor `Foo::Bar.instance_eval{ Module.nesting } # => []`

Comment: @rudolph9 The `nesting` method is one of the few methods like `__dir__`, `binding`, where the literal environment matters. You can't replace it with other constructions even if they are usually equivalent.